# C# web service that gets data from SQL Server 2008 by select query and save it in xml file

Tags: c#, web-services, sql-server-2008

I want to write a C# web service that gets data from a SQL Server 2008 with a `select` query and saves it in a XML file. Note: I use LinQ.

How can I do that?

I used this code but it had more errors .

```
[WebMethod]
public bool Search(string XmlSearch)
{
   using (var MyCon = new MainContextDataContext())
   {
      MyCon.Connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQ_TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

      XElement SearchCust = XDocument.Parse(XmlSearch).Root.Elements().First();

      string AccountNumber = SearchCust.Element("Customer").Attribute("AccountNumber").Value;
      string Phone = SearchCust.Element("Customer").Attribute("PhoneNumber").Value;
      string Name = SearchCust.Element("Customer").Attribute("FirstName").Value;

      if (MyCon.Customers.Where(i => i.AccountNumber == AccountNumber).Count() > 0)
      {
         SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQ_TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT customer.AccountNumber, ShipTo.Address, ShipTo.Address2 FROM Customer FULL OUTER JOIN ShipTo ON customer.AutoID = ShipTo.AutoID WHERE customer.AccountNumber = " + AccountNumber, MyConn);
         cmd.Connection.Open();
         object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
         MyConn.Close();
         SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

         string SRD = string.Empty;

         if (Reader.HasRows)
         {
            if (Reader.Read())
            {
               SRD = Reader.ToString();
            }
         }

         Reader.Close();
         System.Xml.XmlDocument Xdoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
         Xdoc.InnerXml = SRD;
         Xdoc.Save("d:\\xmltest.xml");
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You have a `SELECT` that returns **multiple** columns - yet you call `.ExecuteScalar()` first; this should **only** be used if your `SELECT` returns **exactly one row, exactly one column** (like a `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` command. Also - you then **close** the connection, but you call `cmd.ExecuteReader()` after closing the connection - that of course won't ever work at all! YOu need to (1) open the connection, (2) call `cmd.ExecuteReader()`, (3) iterate over the reader (`while (Reader.Read())`) and (4) get the data from the reader

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: SRD isn't going to contain XML data, so assigning it to the InnerXml property doesn't make sense.  You want to create a "Customer" element and assign attributes on it.